# How to load the newly added data without reloading the page in react?

Tags: reactjs

When I submit a new note, I need to reload my page to see the newly added data. When I click the submit button, the only error that shows in my console log is this `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

I am trying to understand the useContext and useReducer hooks. For me to better understand the code, I have kept the code in just two files.

How can I see the newly added note without reloading the page and how can I get rid of the error?

App.js:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NoteProvider, NotesContext } from "./NoteContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NoteProvider>
      <NotesList />
      <AddNewNote />
    </NoteProvider>
  );
}

function NotesList() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(NotesContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/note", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const { data } = await res.json();
      console.log("data: ", data);
      dispatch({ type: "GET_NOTES", payload: { notes: data } });
    };

    getData();
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.notes.map((note) => {
        return (
          <div key={note._id}>
            <div>{note.title}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function AddNewNote() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(NotesContext);
  const [note, setNote] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await fetch("/api/note", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: note }),
    });

    const data = await res.json()
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_A_NEW_NOTE", payload: { notes: data } });
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setNote(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Note: </label>
        <input className="border" type="text" name="note" onChange={onChange} />
        <button className="border" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

NoteContext.js:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const NotesContext = createContext({
  notes: [],
});

export default function NotesReducer(state, action) {
  const actionPayload = action.payload;
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_NOTES":
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: actionPayload.notes,
      };

    case "ADD_A_NEW_NOTE":
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: [...state.notes, actionPayload]
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function NoteProvider({ children }) {
  const initialState = useContext(NotesContext);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(NotesReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <NotesContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
}
```